# Is there a role that allows me to access the app page (after app registration) to manage the app related info? I'm not admin

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Understand that there is control on Azure portal that allow non-admin to register app but admin are not opening up the access to all people. Is there a way that admin give me access to the app that I own? I need to perform tasks and going through admin is taking substantial overhead.

Comment: What do you mean by "admin give me access to the app that I own"? If you are just a general user and own the registered app, you can access and manage it without any specific role. What is the behavior from your side now? Can you provide any screenshots or more details?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Currently im seeing 

"You do not have access

Your administrator has disabled the App registrations experience in the Azure portal. You can still register or manage applications using PowerShell or another client such as Visual Studio." note that I have not create any app yet. This is the page i see after i click on app registration link.

Comment: So you cannot register Azure AD app on Azure portal? You can only do that through PowerShell or Visual Studio?

Comment: yes, I can't register Azure AD app on Azure portal because the access is blocked by Admin. I think they just turn off "Users can register applications" in the user settings. It is controlled by another team. I was informed by that team that I can't have access to the app ran by our project team, I need to find ways to show them that they can allow us to access to our app page. Doing that through PowerShell or VS is not my choice at the moment.

Comment: May I know what cmd you can use to register app in PowerShell? I asked this question because I have a different behavior. When I turn off "Users can register applications" in the user settings, I can't register application in Azure portal or PowerShell. But I can still access and manage the apps which I registered before.

Comment: No, i have not register any app yet, be it PowerShell, VS or portal. Your second statement is helpful, so i can actually access the app that I created previously even I can't create any now because the settings is off. I think I found the answer, I see owner menu on app page (my personal account for testing purpose), I think the admin team will add me as owner of the app. From there, I could do all the configuration work like you mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: Do you want to write an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Sure. I'll add an answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just a general user and own the registered app, you can access and manage it without any specific role.

Make sure the admin team add you as the owner of the registered apps.

Comment: I have more info. You can access it probably you have access to tenant level but I don't.

Comment: I still cannot access it.

Comment: @hjchin No. I created a new user without assigning any AAD roles to it. Are you sure you are the owner of the application? Can you provide any screenshots?

Comment: sorry for late reply. here is the screenshot 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10ydMJVLPYEZJD0T5IAEEccEFj1HxuIlx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @hjchin There is a link named "Learn more about restricted access" in your screenshot. Please share the link.

Comment: here you go. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#to-restrict-the-default-permissions-for-member-users

Comment: @hjchin I have tried mostly all the related configurations on the link you shared. But none of them would lead to "You do not have access Your administrator has disabled the App registrations experience in the Azure portal. You can still register or manage applications using PowerShell or another client such as Visual Studio." Can you ask your admin what configuration they did?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is due to the following:

> If the user setting "**Restrict access to Azure AD administration portal**" is set to Yes, non-admin users will not be able to use the
> Azure portal to manage the applications they own.

[Owned application registrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#owned-application-registrations) shows Application Owners only get *Update*, *Delete*, and *Restore* permissions, without any corresponding Read access!

The official solution is to add the Application Owners to the [Directory Readers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_IAM#directory-readers) role, which likely gives you more access than is really required:

> **Directory Readers**
>
> Users in this role can read basic directory information. This role
> should be used for:
>
> - Granting a specific set of guest users read access instead of granting it to all guest users.
> - **Granting a specific set of non-admin users access to Azure portal when "Restrict access to Azure AD portal to admins only" is set to
>   "Yes".**
> - Granting service principals access to directory where Directory.Read.All is not an option.

Your admins can however create a new [custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/roles/custom-create#create-a-role-in-the-azure-portal), for example:

Name: Application Reader

| Permission | Description |
| --- | --- |
| microsoft.directory/applications/standard/read | Read standard properties of applications. |

You should then be able to access the App Registrations page, while only being able to amend the apps you own.

Answer (score 0):

You could grant/get yourself granted one of the below roles :

**Application Administrator :**

Users in this role can create and manage all aspects of enterprise applications, application registrations, and application proxy settings.

**Cloud Application Administrator :**

Users in this role have the same permissions as the Application Administrator role, excluding the ability to manage application proxy.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I think the admin team will not give me any admin role which is bigger than our app on the Azure. I'm not azure administrator but consumer of AD. What i need is the access to the app page that we own so that we could do configuration ourselves.